# Is there a way to know the creation date of a folder?

Tags: nautilus, directory

I can't find the creation date in the properties. Is there a way to know? I tried arranging the files by modification as to know which were created first but I don't know if it is in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think creation date is stored. There is a modification date associated with any file, which you can see by running `ls -l` in terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T` should open it). But if you modify any file inside the directory, I believe this modification date is touched.

EDIT: Here's a more precise answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian. Seems like you can see creation date, using debugfs. But only for ext4 fs.

Comment: @GabrielF, if you're referring to `ctime`, please see the comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529543/1771119) which makes it clear that `ctime` isn't the "creation date". According to [this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ctime+3), `ctime` is "call time".

Comment: In ext4, there's also crtime, which is creation time. See here: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

Answer (score 0):

You may try installing KDE Dolphin File Manager: `sudo apt install dolphin`
, and tick/enable "Created" column.

[image]